# docker-py: Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, dockerpy

I am attempting to create a docker image via docker-py and I am using the following code:

```
import docker
import os

docker_client = docker.from_env()
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/container"
docker_client.images.build(path=path, tag='container-tag')
```

The last line throws this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

The user I'm using is a member of the `docker` group and I have checked the permissions of the socket file.

Comment: You are using a normal docker via socket or a remote TLS docker?

Comment: Normal, nothing fancy.

Comment: How about `docker_client.containers.list()` does that work?

Comment: Yes and it returns an empty list.

Comment: That means its not a connection issue. something wrong is going with your build. Run `journalctl -f -n10` in another terminal and then run your code and see if you can find what is going wrong

Comment: That gave me my answer. `Handler for POST /v1.30/build returned error: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `docker_client.containers.list()` works for you, your issue is not with docker connection. It is that the build is failing for some reason.

Run `journalctl -f -n10` in another terminal and then run your code and see if you can find what is going wrong. That will give your clear exception happening when you call

```
docker_client.images.build(path=path, tag='container-tag')
```